# Why is my sign in form not submitting properly in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to php so help will be appreciated.
I am trying to submit this form for signing in.

```
<form method="post" action="sign_in_process.php">
<table>

<tr>
<td>
<label>E-mail: &nbsp;</label>
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" id="e_mail_address" name="email" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="e_passwd">
<label>Password: &nbsp;</label>
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" id="passwd" name="pass"/>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table>
<tr>
<td id="remember-me">
<input type="checkbox" value="remember" id="remember" />
Remember me &nbsp;
</td>
<td>
<button type="submit" id="sign_in_btn" name="sign_in_btn"></button>
</td>
</table>
</form>
```

This is my sign_in_process.php page

```
session_start();
if(isset($POST['sign_in_btn']))
{
$user_email=trim($POST['email']);
$user_password=hash("sha256",$POST['pass']);
check_email($user_email);
check_password($user_password);
if(isset($_SESSION['error']))
        {
        header("Location:sign-in.php");
            }
    else
    {
        $query="SELECT * from user WHERE user_email='$user_email' AND user_password='$user_password'";
        $retrieve=new retrieve();
        $hold=$retrieve-getdata($query);
        if($hold['user_active']==1)
        {
            $_SESSION['login']==true;
            $_SESSION['email']=$user_email;
            $_SESSION['pass']=$user_password;
            $_SESSION['username']=$hold['user_name'];
            $_SESSION['user_id']=$hold['user_id'];
            header("Location:index.php");

            }
            else if($hold['user_active']==0)
            {
                echo "you have to activate your account first by clicking the link we have sent you on your email";

                }
                else if(!$holder)
                {

                    echo "invalid user";
                    }
}
}
```

But when i try to sign in then nothing happens though i can see in the URL that form is submitted and it does go to sign_in_process.php but it doesn't perform anything it simply shows a blank page.
In the code above check_email and check_password are simply the functions i m using for validation which i have in my functions.php file. I am requiring that function class with require_once.

Comment: Have you checked the server / application log? Blank pages usually mean you have the error output turned off.

Comment: Throw this at the top of your PHP file: `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(-1);`

Comment: Unrelated to the problem, but type for password field should be `type="password"`. That makes it hide the password as you type it in with those * things.

Comment: @rockethazmat it is still not showing any error. i have used ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(-1); too.
i have made signup just before signin everything worked fine there.
i am using almost the same technique over here but i seems like doing nothing on sign_in_process.php page

Comment: Make sure you clear cookies etc.  Sometimes it takes a bit for pages to get pushes unless you do a hard refresh

Comment: I just noticed this, it's `$_POST`, not `$POST`.  (Also, try adding a `value` to the `sign_in_btn`.)

Comment: @rocketHazmat thank you. It was not submitting because of _ problem.
and why to use vlaue for sign_in_btn?

Comment: missing a `name` on the remember me, and you dont need a name (or value) on the submit.  Also, doubt its the cause, but use an `input` with `type=submit` for your submit button, not a `button`. And as someone already said by the time I hit addComment, you are checking $POST, where you should be checking $_POST. so it is correctly doing  nothing. Add a final print "goodbye"; to the end of the file, to show that you are getting to the end of the script vs the "blank error page of death"

Comment: @user3570249: I wasn't sure if it would still post without a value, or if it did, it might be blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just added the underscore to the $_POST.
Also you should never trust user input, so I added the mysql_real_escape_string(); :)
And the «name»-attribute is missing at the "remember me" button

```
if(isset($_POST['sign_in_btn']))
{
$user_email=trim($_POST['email']);
$user_password=hash("sha256",$_POST['pass']);
check_email($user_email);
check_password($user_password);
if(isset($_SESSION['error']))
        {
        header("Location:sign-in.php");
            }
    else
    {
        $user_email=mysql_real_escape_string($user_email);
        $user_password=mysql_real_escape_string($user_password);
        $query="SELECT * from user WHERE user_email='$user_email' AND user_password='$user_password'";
        $retrieve=new retrieve();
        $hold=$retrieve-getdata($query);
        if($hold['user_active']==1)
        {
            $_SESSION['login']==true;
            $_SESSION['email']=$user_email;
            $_SESSION['pass']=$user_password;
            $_SESSION['username']=$hold['user_name'];
            $_SESSION['user_id']=$hold['user_id'];
            header("Location:index.php");

            }
            else if($hold['user_active']==0)
            {
                echo "you have to activate your account first by clicking the link we have sent you on your email";

                }
                else if(!$holder)
                {

                    echo "invalid user";
                    }
}
}
?>
```